# Dynamic virtual hosts with different backend port in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I'm looking to create a series of subdomains for an application, each of the subdomains get their own backend server via mod_proxy.

I'd like to avoid generating a new vhost every time this happens, and instead rely on the naming scheme (subdomains are numericaly based).

So let's say domain would be `promotion-4321.example.com` and backend server would be listening on port `4321`

Can I create apache configuration that extracts `4321` from host name (and catches all `promotion-XXXX.example.com`) and uses it to direct request to backend on port `4321` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to catch all request to the server in a virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
# [ Server Domain ]
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias *
...
```

Then you need to create a rule to catch the information you need

```
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} promotion-(.*?)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://backend.example.com:%1$1 [P,QSA]
...
```

- `%1` will be the variable catched by the RewriteCond regexp
- `$1` will be the current url request catched by the RewriteRule regexp

If you don't want to use rewrite rule, you can use ProxyRemoteMatch :

```
ProxyRemoteMatch promotion-(.*?)\.example\.com http://backend.example.com:$1
```

Comment: What If I'm using mod_proxy ? How i define backend.example.com ? (all the backend servers are on localhost btw)

Comment: [P] is proxying request. The trouble with `ProxyPassMatch` is you can only make your redirect depending on request and not on hostname. So you would have to use `ProxyRemoteMatch promotion-(.*?)\.example\.com http://backend.example.com:$1` i edited my answer with this information